# How to validate Forms in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, validation

Is it better to validate PHP forms using php and then redirecting with errors, or is it better to use javascript validation and then just allow form submission if javascript is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use javascript to validate format, e.g. email format, password length, etc.

use php to validate db if same record exists, e.g. same username

except hackers, 99% ppl enable javascript, so just throw this worry away.

here I recommend [jquery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) for client side validation.

Comment: I agree with matt. for further safety, server side validation for each field should be done. I was just pointing out the first step to implement regarding usability and simplicity

Comment: "except hackers, 99% ppl enable javascript" do you have any hard data to back that up?

Answer (score 11):

You **must** validate values on the server side, since the client cannot be trusted.

You **may** validate values on the client side to provide better UX for those with JavaScript enabled.

Comment: And if the client is running IE `!@#$ing` 6?

Comment: +1 for being like my answer, only better. More concise and straightforward.

Comment: Yes @Tesserex, i agree to you for a +1

Answer (score 4):

I usually do both. If you can check the fields in javascript, it saves them the loading time and spares your server the hit. You still have to check again on the server in case they had javascript disabled, or intentionally bypassed it.

Comment: If you only do one, it should be on the server side. As above, client side can be bypassed and I'm guessing you don't want your security bypassed. Client side is a great UX practice, but not secure.

Answer (score 1):

Is better making both together because php can handle raw request without using or enabling javascript, javascript, can speed-up the check process and handle it in an elegant graphic way

Answer (score 1):

Definitely both. Users can turn off Javascript or even edit your validation script since it is local (using Firebug or some other such tool). Yes, this means that you will likely write the same validation script in two separate languages at approximately the same time, but that's an essential way to avoid incorrect or malformed data from being submitted.